# NSRecursivelock v NSNotification performance

Tags: arrays, xcode, multithreading, nsnotification

So I was using an array to hold objects, then iterating over them to call a particular method. As the objects in this array could be enumerated/mutated on different threads I was using an `NSRecursiveLock`.

I then realised that as this method is always called on every object in this array, I could just use an `NSNotification` to trigger it, and do away with the array and lock.

I am just double checking that this is a good idea? `NSNotification` will be faster than a lock, right?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement.  There is normally only a requirement to lock the array if you are adding/removing objects from it.  Using the objects in an array typically wouldn't require the lock to be used at the array-level, and instead if the method requires single-thread access, it needs to implement locking itself.

Comment: i usually use a pattern where modifications to the array are done under a lock and a notification is sent out afterwards, while everyone else uses an immutable copy of the array.

Comment: Sorry, adding and removal was performed on the array too, so a lock was required. However, I realised the array wasn't really required, and I could instead used a volatile uint32_t and atomic increment and decrement to replace the array logic. Basically, I was using arrays and locks to accomplish what I realised could be done with nsnotification and a counter. I wanted to check that this would indeed be a better approach, from a performance point of view, else I may revert back to the array and lock. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that the locking should be done on the *objects*, not on the array. You are not mutating the array, but the objects. So you need one mutex per object. It will give you a finer granularity and allow concurrent updates to different objects to proceed in parallel (it wouldn't with a global lock).

Second, a recursive lock is complete overkill. If you wish to have mutual exclusion on the objects, each object should have a standard mutex. If what you are doing inside the critical section is cpu bound and really short, you might consider using a spinlock (it won't even trap in the OS. Only use for *short* CPU bound critical sections though). Recursive mutex are meant to be used when a thread k can (because of its logic) acquire another lock on an object it has already locked himself (hence the recursive name).

Third, NSNotifications (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/) will allocate memory, drop the notification in a notification Center, do locking to actually implement that (the adding to the center) and finally dispatch the notifications in the center and deallocate the notification. So it is *heavier* than a plain simple locking. It "hides" the synchronization APIs inside the center, but it does not eliminate them, and you pay the price of memory allocations/deallocations.

If you wish to modify the array (add/remove), then you should also synchronize on these operations, but that would be unfortunate as access to independent entries of the array would now collide.

Hope that helps.